# Keras Tuner hyperband epoch

Tags: keras, keras-tuner

I am running Keras Tuner(Hyperband) since Random search does not find optimal solution, I would like to know how we can control the number of models and epochs to run. In Randomsearch we can clearly give it in max trials and execution per trial but I don't find this parameter in Hyperband. I could see max_epoch in hyperband but how it is being used if I specify epochs=100 while doing tuner.search

Can you please help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that it does not have *max_trials* parameter, but the total epochs can be estimated by

```
max_epochs * (math.log(max_epochs, factor) ** 2) * iteration
```

as indicated in the [document](https://keras.io/api/keras_tuner/tuners/hyperband/).